# How to parameterize SQL query when the parameter can sometimes be NULL?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, t-sql, pyodbc

With `pyodbc` I can parametrize the query like this;

```
value = "testval"

query = \
    """
    SELECT *
    FROM TestTable
    WHERE Column = ?;
    """

cursor.execute(query, value)
```

But the problem is that if the `value` is None, the query should look like this;

```
value = None

query = \
    """
    SELECT *
    FROM TestTable
    WHERE Column IS NULL;
    """

cursor.execute(query)
```

So how should the query look like when the `value` can either be None or a string;

```
value = get_value()  # can return a string or None

query = \
    """
    SELECT *
    FROM TestTable
    WHERE Column ???????????
    """

cursor.execute(query, value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use the ISO/ANSI standard `NULL`-safe comparison:

```
WHERE Column IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ?
```

Not all databases support this, so you can also use:

```
WHERE Column = ? OR (Column IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)
```

If you are reluctant to pass the parameter twice, you can include it in the `FROM` clause:

```
. . .
FROM . . . CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT ? as compColumn) params
WHERE (Column = params.compColumn0 or (Column IS NULL and params.compColumn IS NULL)
```

Comment: Am I correct that the first one will not work with sql-server?